# ordenar post por cantidad de comentarios eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

lo que quiero lograr es ordenar los post que recibo pero de mayor a menor por cantidad de comentarios,
este codigo me devuelve los post por fecha de creacion

```
$post = Post::orderBy('id','DESC')->with(['user','comment','category','tagged'])->get();
```

pero no sé como lograr filtrar por la cantidad de comentarios que esta en otro modelo...

Comment: si, asi como puse la consulta de ejemplo funciona perfectamente.

Comment: no, tengo que llamar todas las demas relaciones tambien..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models), que colocará una columna `{relación}_count` en los modelos resultantes. Luego puedes ordenar por esa columna:

```
$post = Post::with([
    'user',
    'comment',
    'category',
    'tagged'
])
->withCount('comment')
->orderBy('comment_count','DESC')
->get();
```

También, en vez de:

```
->orderBy('comment_count','DESC')
```

puedes usar:

```
->latest('comment_count')
```

para [Ordenar los resultados en la consulta](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) en orden descendente.

Comment: Gracias crack!! funciono perfectamente